# What is correct name prefix for subclass of UITableView (UICollectionView)

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Is there some authority recommendations what form of prefix should be used for UITableView (UICollectionView) - plural or singular? On example:

1. UserNamesTableView or UserNameTableView? (table that presents many users), or ObjectsTableView vs ObjectTableView (table presents many objects) etc.
2. Accordingly: UserNamesTableViewCell or UserNameTableViewCell?

Comment: No, because you are responsible to name them as needed. Suggestion: use plural if class is supposed to handle multiple stuff and singular if class will handle one kind of something at a time. Which is why you will not find someting like UITableCellsView or NSUsersDefault or NSNotificationsCenters.

Comment: Apple seems uses singular form in their example  (`MealTableViewCell` and `MealTableViewController`): https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html although you can claim that for table they should've used plural (table displays meals, not one meal, so could be `MealsTableViewController`)

Comment: But there is only one table in `MealTableViewController` and you can not inherit Meals from it. The naming conventions are focused on the Object that is defined rather than the objects that can be hold. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW1

Comment: @KirilS. my question is about UITableView, not TableViewController. So, what is correct for your opinion, `MealsTableView` or `MealTableView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming convention should be focused on the object that is defined with the class rather than the objects that can be hold by the class.

So if you name something `User` it should define an object that is definition of one user.
Possibly kind of **NSObject**.

But if you name something `Users` you may have defined a Type/Class that can hold Users.
Possibly kind of **NSArray**.

So a `UserTableViewController` is definition of one table that is meant to address **User objects** and not **Users objects** even if it can hold cells which are feed by `Users` and each shows content of one `User`.

So with `UsersTableViewController` i would expect a TableViewController that can mangle multiple users per cell and not one user per cell.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW1

So cause you asked for..

You can anser that allways when asking yourself what is the Object type that is defined and not what objects can be hold by the type.
What do would someone expect is UserTableView handling?

- a TableView that handles objects of type User?
- or a TableView that handles objects of type Users?

so the answer is quite simple. It would be most logic to use UserTableView.

Comment: My question is about UsersTableView/UserTableView, not ViewController. Could you correct answer for this case?

Comment: where is written about ViewController? It does'nt matter, the naming convention is the same. a TableView is a view that handles a table which is for objects of user and not of object of users.

Answer (score 1):

In general the only *rule* is that you must not accidentally use a name that might be already in use by the built-in frameworks (because Objective-C has no namespaces). The way to avoid that is never to begin a type name with two prefix capital letters, such as ABThing, as that is what the built-in Cocoa frameworks do.

Starting with a word (so that the second character is a small letter) is generally fine, though in Swift you can never *guarantee* that you won't clash with an existing name (I see people make the mistake all the time in Swift of calling a type Data or Date, for instance).

Otherwise, no, there are no recommendations or rules; it would all just be a matter of convenience and convention. As a matter of best practices you should probably try to be clear as to what something is, but that's purely a matter of opinion right there.